# What Literary device is in use, when the tone/pronunciation/intonation/delivery of a word or phrase gives its double meaning

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, speech, literary-techniques, literary-device

> Towards the climax of the whodunit movie "knives out" when the poisoned maid Fran says "You did this" she is in fact saying "hugh did this"; hugh being the name of her assailant.

What is the literary device used in the above scenario called?

Comment: Search 'eggcorn' on this site, you might find  a duplicate

Comment: It's specifically not a literary device because letters don't have intonation or pronunciation. Only real oral language, not written letters, makes sounds and allows disambiguation based on them. It's hard enough to "talk" about pronunciation online, using letters, without getting confused with Greek terms. And "Reveal Spoiler" is not a scenario.

Comment: Probably “foreshadowing”:  where the author subtly lets the reader know the ending or an upcoming event. He or she may foreshadow the future by using phrases, imagery, or events.

Comment: No I wanted something along the lines of 'this information conveys one thing, when in actuality it alludes to something else'